# How can I parse a bytestring in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.5, string-parsing, python-unicode

Basically, I have two bytestrings in a single line like this:

```
b'\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\x96 - \xe0\xa6\xb6\xe0\xa6\x96\n'
```

This is a [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) string that I'm importing from an online file using `urllib`, and I want to compare the individual bytestrings so that I can replace the wrong ones. However, I can't find out any way to parse the string so that I get `\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\x96` and `\xe0\xa6\xb6\xe0\xa6\x96` in two different variables.

I tried converting it into a raw string like `str(b'\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\x96')` and the indexing actually works, but in that case I can't revert back to the original bytestring in the first place.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend trying something like this...

```
arr = b'\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\x96 - \xe0\xa6\xb6\xe0\xa6\x96\n'

splt = arr.decode().split(' - ')

b_arr1 = splt[0].encode()
b_arr2 = splt[1].encode()
```

I tried it out in the Python 3 terminal and it works fine.

Comment: Hey that works! Thank you so much!
Just one more question, how do I get rid of the newline character at the end of the second bytestring? Same `decode()` - `encode()` procedure, I hope?

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this:

```
a = b'\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\x96 - \xe0\xa6\xb6\xe0\xa6\x96\n'

parts = [part.strip() for part in a.decode().split('-')]

first_part = parts[0].encode()
second_part = parts[1].encode()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the strip() function?

Comment: @JakeStephens it strips off the white space, leaving only the the needed chars. Just in case there is more than one space before and after `-`

Comment: Typically you don't want to do that when working with binary data... it's not real text, what you consider a "space" may be not what you think.